# How to extract files recursively but keep them in their own folders?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zip, epub

This is how I'm extracting all the files in a folder (recursively):

```
find -iname \*.epub -exec unzip -o {} \;
```

But the extracted files end up all in the parent folder:

```
Parent (Extracted Epub files)
  Child (Epub files)
  Child (Epub files)
```

How to change that command, so that they are extracted in their own folders?

```
Parent
  Child (Epub files and extracted Epub files)
  Child (Epub files and extracted Epub Files)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you’re using GNU `find`, use its `-execdir` action:

```
find -iname \*.epub -execdir unzip -o {} \;
```

This will run `unzip` from each directory where files are found, ensuring that the files are extracted in the appropriate subdirectory.

If you specify the start directory this will also work on at least some BSDs ([OpenBSD in particular](https://man.openbsd.org/find)):

```
find /path/to/start -iname \*.epub -execdir unzip -o -- {} \;
```

Comment: Note that `-execdir` is from BSD, it's not GNU-specific (though not standard and not supported by every implementation). `-iname` and omiting the file/dir you want to search are also non-standard extensions. With BSD finds, you'll want `unzip -o -- {}`. You'd also want `-nw` to stop `zip` itself from interpreting wildcards.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the info! Why is `-nw` (or rather, `zip`) significant here?

Comment: Without `-nw`, `unzip '*.zip'` would unzip all the zip files in the current directory instead of just the `*.zip` file. `unzip` behaves more in a MS-DOS way by default.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, I get that, but as you wrote yourself, `-nw` is an option for `zip`. It’s not supported by `unzip`.

Comment: D'oh, I hadn't realised `unzip` didn't have anyway to disable that wildcard processing. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is a somewhat unfortunate oversight :-(. (The lack of the option, not your not realising it!)

Comment: I also just found out that wildcards are only considered in the last component of the file path (`unzip '*/*.epub'`  unzips all the epub files in the `*` directory). And also `unzip '[*].epub'` would `unzip` `*.epub` but if it can't find it, would unzip `[*].epub` instead (or possibly `[*].epub.zip`... Such a bad API...

Comment: Yes, applying DOS wildcard handling to all platforms (the `*/*.epub` behaviour matches DOS expectations), and then trying to add userfriendly sugar on top, produces questionable results.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Kitt's `-execdir` answer is good, **but** if it's possible for multiple `.epub` files to be in the same directory (so `-execdir` doesn't help), you'd need to do something like this:

```
find ./ -iname '*.epub' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    rp="$(realpath -e "$f")"
    bn="$(basename "$f" .epub)"
    dn="$(dirname "$rp")/$bn"

    [ -e "$dn" ] && continue
    echo mkdir -p "$dn"
    echo unzip -d "$dn" -o "$rp"
  done' find-sh {} +
```

For each argument (`"$f"`) passed to the sh script, this uses `realpath` to get its full absolute pathname into variable `rp`, and `basename` is then used to get the base filename without the .epub extension into variable `bn`.  `dirname` is used to get the absolute directory name, and `"/$bn"` is appended to give us variable `dn`.  BTW, all three of these programs are in GNU [coreutils](http://gnu.org/software/coreutils).

if `"$dn"` already exists, it is skipped with the `continue` statement (this would be a good place to add more error-checking and error-handling code, if required).  Otherwise, it is created with `mkdir -p` and used as the argument to unzip's `-d` option.  `"$rp"` is used as the filename arg to `unzip`.

NOTE: This is written as a dry-run, so it only prints what it **would** do, without actually doing it.  Remove the `echo` statements from the commands to make it actually create the directories and extract the .epub files into them.

You might want to add an `echo "$rp"` or `echo "$f"` statement and use `unzip`'s `-q` option to reduce the amount of noise being output while still showing progress as it iterates through the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` and a `find` implementation with support for the now common (though not standard) `-iname`/`-print0` predicates, you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -iname '?*.epub' \
              ! -name '*[[*?]*' \
              ! -iname ..epub \
              ! -iname ...epub \
                -type f -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C sed -z 'h;s/\.epub$//;p;g' |
  xargs -r0n2 unzip -d
```

(skipping the file names that contain `[`, `*` or `?` characters to work around a misfeature of `unzip` whereby it treats them as wildcards to look for matching files).

Which would run

```
unzip -d ./path/to/file ./path/to/file.epub
```

To extract the contents of the `epub` file into the directory named after the file without the extension.

We also skip `.epub` (with `?*` needing at least one byte before `.`), `..epub` and `...epub` files as the corresponding directory would be `""`, `.` and `..` which would be a problem.

Or with zsh:

```
set -o extendedglob
for f (./**/(^*[[*?]*).(#i)epub(N.)) unzip -d $f:r $f
```

here omitting hidden ones, change the glob to `./**/(^(|.|..|*[[?*]*)).(#i)epub(ND.)` if you want them (and again excluding `.epub`, `..epub`, `...epub`).

With `zsh`, we could better address the problem with `[`, `?`, `*` characters by replacing `*` with `[*]`, `?` with `[?]`...

```
set -o extendedglob
for f (./**/*.(#i)epub(N.)) unzip -d $f:r $f:h/${${f:t}//(#m)[[?*]/[$MATCH]}
```

Or you could use a more Unixy command to extract the zip archives such as libarchive's `bsdtar`:

```
set -o extendedglob
for f (**/*.(#i)epub(N.)) {
  mkdir -p -- $f:r && bsdtar -C $f:r -xf $f
}
```

Or, using `find` and including hidden ones:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -iname '?*.epub' ! -iname ..epub ! -iname ...epub -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    dir=${file%.*}
    mkdir -p "$dir" &&
      bsdtar -C "$dir" -xf "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```